# Has the phenomenon of equating two different ideas been studied?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, political-philosophy, philosophy-of-economics

While reading Henry Kissinger's book, *Diplomacy*, I came across several examples of thinkers conveniently, but constructively (meaning with good intentions), equating one concept with another. The quotes are below.

> Adam Smith, in *The Wealth of Nations*, maintained that an "invisible hand" would distill general economic well-being out of selfish individual economic actions. (p.21)

> In *The Federalist Papers*, Madison argued that, in a large enough republic, the various political "factions" selfishly pursuing their own interests would, by a kind of automatic mechanism, forge a proper domestic harmony. (p.21)

> The same principles were applied to international affairs. By pursuing its own selfish interests, each state was presumed to... [guarantee] that freedom of choice for each state assured well-being for all. (p.22)

> In foreign policy, Great Britain has always tended to practice a convenient form of ethical egoism: what was good for Great Britain was considered good for the rest of the world as well. (p.598)

The third quote is in reference to balance-of-power politics.

I have a couple of questions about this kind of dogmatic thinking where two different ideas are, potentially incorrectly, equated:

1. Is there a term for equating two ideas in this way? I was thinking of Orwell's doublespeak, but that seemed inappropriate since the quoted ideas were thought to be for betterment of life, whereas doublespeak was constructed in the story for perpetuating an authoritarian regime.
2. Would you to be able to provide any other examples or references for studying this phenomenon of equating two ideas?

EDIT: while reading over what I wrote, I realized that the first three examples, and possible the fourth too, are not actually equalities, but rather implications. So answers about fallacious implications would be fine.

Comment: I don't see how the examples you gave are examples of a thinker equating two different ideas. What are the ideas being equated, and who is doing the equating?

Comment: This is called analogy, and yes, political and social studies are full of loose analogies. Considering the complexity of matters there, and intractability of exact modeling, it is not a bad heuristic for guessing what might work to look at what works in analogous situations where it is known. Analogies always limp, of course, but they are better than nothing. Your examples are heuristic arguments of this sort, and there is nothing wrong with them as such. Of course, the plausibility of conclusions depends on how far the analogy actually holds, but that may not be discernible from the outset.

Comment: @Conifold I thought about it and realized that what strikes me about these examples is that they give one an excuse to pursue one's own self-interest on the basis of it serving a greater purpose. I looked up the term Kissinger uses "ethical egoism" and it seems to be a special case of your word "analogy": https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egoism/#EthiEgoi . "Ethical egoism claims that I morally ought to perform some action if and only if, and because, performing that action maximizes my self-interest."

Comment: Also remember to distinguish between analogies and mere *[categorical thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization)*, which is commonplace in politics, often misleadingly equating phenomena with similar appearances or features. See [association fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy) and [pigeonholing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonholing).

Comment: [Metaphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor?wprov=sfla1).

Comment: I can't follow your point. The four examples are simply proposed sociopolitical mechanisms for social outcomes--and those proposed mechanisms may or may not be correct. I don't understand what you mean by "Equating one concept with another" or "fallacious implications." As it stands, the question should be closed as it's too unclear what is being asked.

Comment: @Chelonian I was motivated to make this post because, as Kissinger implies, there are patterns of thought in these Enlightenment-era ideas. I have tried to point out some such patterns, like in my comment above about ethical egoism. My goal is to determine whether the examples fall into a more general framework, and to know whether there are other examples. Sorry that I am not being more precise. I guess philosophy is sometimes like this, where we have a general feeling and wish to enquire further.

Comment: Since you are interested specifically in the claims that individually optimal actions result in collectively optimal outcome there are well-known counterexamples to this that have also been discussed since the Enlightenment. They are grouped under the [collective action problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_action_problem). The better known examples are the prisoner's dilemma and the tragedy of the commons. This sort of thing is studied in game theory.

Comment: Then really your question should be removed and replaced with something like "Is there a general term for the school(s) of thought in political philosophy that individually optimal actions result in collectively optimal outcomes, as these four quotes propose?" And hat tip to @Conifold for that phrasing.

Comment: Btw, the "selfish interests" interpretation of the invisible hand is Samuelson's 1948 invention that he misattributed to Smith, see [Kennedy, The ‘Invisible Hand’ Phenomenon in Economics](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1057%2F9781137321053_11.pdf). For game theoretic analysis of Samuelson's hand see [Brandenburger-Stuart, The Invisible Hand](https://adambrandenburger.com/aux/material/ab_articles_essays/tih-12-08-131.pdf).